# Jquery UI range Slider values bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please help me.
This code is working

```
$slider.slider({
    min: 0
    ,max: 500
    ,range: true
    ,values: [0,500]
    ,step: 10
    ,slide: function (event, ui){
        $prev.text('₴' + ui.values[0]);
        $next.text('₴' + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
```

this code - dont (range slider disabled, but place correct numbers) :

```
var minel = 280;
var maxel = 495;

$slider.slider({
    min: minel
    ,max: maxel
    ,range: true
    ,values: [minel,maxel]
    ,step: 10
    ,slide: function (event, ui){
            $prev.text('₴' + ui.values[0]);
            $next.text('₴' + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
```

have tested my code, problem is near previous code:

if:

```
var maxel = 500;
var minel = 100;
```

everything is working. But its not constants, i parse elements on page to get min and max price. Code example:

```
 var arr = [];

    $(".priceeeee").each(function(indx){
        arr.push($(this).html());
    });

    var maxel = arr[0];
    var minel = arr[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (maxel < arr[i]) {
            maxel = arr[i];
        };
        if (minel > arr[i]) {
            minel = arr[i];
        };
    };
```

Comment: Your code works for me, what version of jquery and jqueryui are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/uk4c7hr2/

Comment: jquery-1.9.1, jquery-ui-1.11.2 last stable

Comment: @Codrin Eugeniu i use it with nice jquery filter plugin, mb it will help. [jplist](https://jplist.com/jqueryuiexamples/range-slider)

Comment: In the link you posted, they initialize like : `ui_slider: function ($slider, $prev, $next) {` Are those vars properly defined?

Comment: @Codrin Eugeniu i have updated code above, look at it please.

Answer (score 0):

I used parseInt for parsed numbers.

```
maxel = parseInt(maxel);
minel = parseInt(minel);
```

Thx 2 @Codrin Eugeniu for fast feedback!

Comment: No worries not sure what I did :) Also `parseInt` should be used with a base, as in `parseInt(maxel, 10)`.